# Three Js load from external source?

Tags: javascript, magento, three.js, blender

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 60vw; height: 60vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>



 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>


<script>
  
  "use strict";

const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});

// There's no reason to set the aspect here because we're going
// to set it every frame anyway so we'll set it to 2 since 2
// is the the aspect for the canvas default size (300w/150h = 2)
const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff80C0, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
    // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // set render target sizes here
  }
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
</script>
```

I am facing an problem where I am not able to find a correct work-around:

I am working on an website project where I cannot upload any files like .glb or .json directly and load them in my three js code because I am only working through the Magento 2 WYSIWYG editor. Here I can only add some HTML, CSS, Java...
So I am stuck on how to load an object which I have created using Blender 2.79.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to be able to use an in Blender created object in this project? 
I am absolutely new to web development and I have no idea if I can upload such files anywhere on my server and load them after that or how to achieve this.

Thank you all in advance, 
best regards
Mathias

*Code so far: I have only a cube added into an container, I would like to load an blender object instead of that cube.

Comment: Can you share with us the code that shows what you've done so far?

Comment: I have added to code above, at the time I only have an cube rotating in an container. I would love to load an blender .glb file instead of that cube but I don't know how to do that if I cannot simply upload the .glb file into my Magento backend.

Comment: Using a glb file [is pretty easy](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html). I have no idea [how to upload files to magneto](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/cms/media-storage.html)

Comment: But is there no other way, like uploading it to an external website and load it from there via the url or something like this?